# Are Transmission values for absorptive light filters proportional to Intensity?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light

Mostly filter rates are given in percent, but if I imagine that for example 10 photons hit an absorption filter with 50%, molecules are excited there and in the end only 5 get through while the other 5 have led to heating, why should 10 photons suddenly be absorbed with 20? ***Does this simply have to do with the hit probability?*** And what if the intensity becomes so high that the molecules break? How is this prevented with UV filters? Why don't sunglasses for example heat up until they start to burn when they are in the sun, after all the absorbed energy has to go somewhere else than in vibration, rotation and translation, that would become more and more in the filter with time... and as a photon to radiate again would be pretty bad because you want to prevent that in sunglasses.

Or another example, how does a black surface get rid of the absorbed energy from light without re emitting photons again? (Ok, maybe the vibrational energy could re transmittet to the surrounding gas molecules but what if there's a vacuum around that black surface? Would it be enough to simply point a very weak lighting source on it for a very long time to reach the burning point?)

So are those filter transmission values given in % actually themselve light intensity dependent?